# TypeScript: is there a difference between Entity[] & array<Entity>?

Tags: typescript

All in title,

e.g.

```
users: User[];
users: array<User>;
```

What is the difference? Is there one a better practice than the other?

*nb: I couldn't find information about this & I see both in source code.*

Comment: `array` isn't a built-in type. Did you mean `Array`? If so then, `User[]` is just syntactic sugar for `Array<User>`, and which version you use is purely up to your preferences, but I would prefer `User[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`users: User[];` is a valid type.

`users: array<User>;` is not a valid type. You will get an error `Cannot find name 'array'`.

You can create your interface like below.

```
export interface Person {
    users: User[];
}

export interface User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```